# I can not send a specific data (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble with my code I can not recover this data my array. Do you have an idea? Thank you.

I can not get my data inside my array outside my loop..

Node.js/Mongoose :

Controllers :

```
exports.newsfeedContent = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const decoded = req.decoded;
        await newsfeedContentQueries(decoded, req, res, next);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(['erreur'],e)        
    }
};
```

Queries :

```
exports.newsfeedContentQueries = function (decoded, req, res, next) {
    const sub = decoded;
    User.findOne({
        '_id': sub
    }).exec().then((user) => {
        User.findOne({
                'amis': user.amis
            }).exec()
            .then((user) => {
                let tab = []
                for (let index = 0; index < user.amis.length; index++) {
                    MessageUser.find({'userID': user.amis[index]}).exec().then((UserMessage)=>{
                        for (let index2 = 0; index2 < UserMessage.length; index2++) {

                            tab.push(UserMessage[index2].message) //<= The data I want to recover.
                            console.log(tab); // <= Here my array to all the data.

                        }
                    }) 
                }
                console.log(tab) // <= Here my array sends me = []
                req.newsfeedUser = tab // <= what I would like to do, but my array is empty.. 
                next()
            })
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

User.js :

```
router.get('/newsfeed', verify, newsfeedContent, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.newsfeedUser); // Here my array sends me = []
});
```

Comment: `MessageUser.find` is asynchronous, which means your variable `tab` is filled later than when you print it... You have to wait for your promise before you do something on/with the result.

Comment: do you have any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: It seems you iterate on something and have a promise for each iteration. What you must do is put each promise in an array, then you use `Promise.all` to wait for all promise to be completed. `Promise.all` returns a promise that will be resolved when all the subpromises are resolved, so you just do: `Promise.all(myPromises).then(() => console.log(tab));` Use `then` to perform something once everything is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I successful .. I did not know that when I supply a array as a value, it would be automatically by mongoose iterated.

```
exports.newsfeedContentQueries = async function (decoded, req, res, next) {

    const user = await User.findOne({
        '_id': decoded
    }).exec().then((data) => {
        return data
    });

    const messageList = await MessageUser.find({
        'userID': user.amis
    }).exec().then((data) => {
        return data
    });
    res.json(messageList);
};
```